# How to handle restful web service response in react native?

Tags: rest, react-native

This is how I'm calling a web service.

```
fetch('http://**someurl**', {  
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    username : "admin",
    password: "admin123",
  })
})
```

When I call it from postman I get a response like this :

```
{
    "code": 1,
    "message": {
        "Object1": [
            {
                "Id": 1,
                "Name": "COWDUNG",
                "manufacturer": "OWN",
                "description": "ORGANIC MANUER",
                "type": "Fertilizer"
            }
           ]
         }
     }
```

> Can anyone tell me how to handle the response?

Comment: [Documentation is helpful](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
    username : "admin",
    password: "admin123",
  })
}).then((response) => response.json()).then((responseJson) => {
        // you'll get the response in responseJson
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        //you will get error here.
    });
```

Comment: alert(responseJson);

but i would recommend to use console.log() rather than alert.

Comment: from where i can get the log?

Comment: by using react native command 
 'react-native log-android' for android &
'react-native log-ios' for ios